# dlsym can't find symbol in .so

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to learn to write a read-eval-print-loop for c like python shell. My program read a function or expression from stdin, then write to a temp file and compile it into shared object, finally load .so file into process space by dlopen and invoke the function found by dlsym. My code is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  static char line[4096];
  char str[256];
  int fd;
  FILE *fp;
  int cnt = 0;
  int isfunc = 0;
  void *handle;
  int (*func)();
  while (1) {
    printf("crepl> ");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (!fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
      break;
    }
    // create a temp file
    char template[] = "/tmp/crepltempXXXXXX";
    fd = mkstemp(template);
    if (fd == -1) {
      perror("mkstemp");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // write function to file
    fp = fdopen(fd, "w");
    assert(fp);
    sscanf(line, "%s", str);
    if (!strcmp(str, "int")) {  // function, assume it only has int type
      fprintf(fp, "%s", line);
      isfunc = 1;
    } else {  // expression wrapped by function
      fprintf(fp, "int __expr_wrapper_%d() {\n", cnt++);
      fprintf(fp, "\treturn %s;", line);
      fprintf(fp, "}\n");
      isfunc = 0;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    // compile it into shared object
    sprintf(str, "gcc -fPIC -shared -x c -w %s -o /tmp/crepllib.so", template);
    system(str);
    // load .so
    handle = dlopen("/tmp/crepllib.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if (!handle) {
      fprintf(stderr, "dlopen error: %s\n", dlerror());
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // find function and invoke it
    if (!isfunc) {  // expression
      sprintf(str, "__expr_wrapper_%d", cnt - 1);
      func = dlsym(handle, str);
      if (!func) {
        fprintf(stderr, "dlsym error: %s\n", dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      printf("%d\n", func());
    } else {      // function
      printf("ok\n");
    }
  }
}
```

But problem occurs when I run it. Firstly, I define a function f() and all is OK. Secondly, I define a expression but get a error. The dlsym can't find my function name.

```
➜  crepl git:(main) ✗ make run
gcc -m64 -g -std=gnu11 -ggdb -Wall -Werror -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-value -Wno-unused-variable ./crepl.c -o crepl-64 -ldl
./crepl-64
crepl> int f(){return 1;}
ok
crepl> f()
dlsym error: /tmp/crepllib.so: undefined symbol: __expr_wrapper_0
make: *** [Makefile:5: run] Error 1
```

So I list symbol in /tmp/crepllib.so and find __expr_wrapper_0 is defined. I do not understand what happened? Can someone help me please?

```
➜  /tmp nm crepllib.so
0000000000003e60 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000004000 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
00000000000020c0 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000002000 r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
0000000000004028 d __TMC_END__
                 w __cxa_finalize
00000000000010d0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000003e58 d __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000004020 d __dso_handle
0000000000001119 T __expr_wrapper_0
0000000000003e50 d __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000001130 t _fini
0000000000001000 t _init
0000000000004028 b completed.8061
0000000000001060 t deregister_tm_clones
                 U f
0000000000001110 t frame_dummy
0000000000001090 t register_tm_clones
```

Comment: I bet dlopen is just returning the same .so handle again because you never closed it and so it's still loaded and it doesn't need to load it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you actually have a number of issues in the code:

- As mentioned in comments, you need to `dlclose` before doing another `dlopen`.
- On any `return` into your repl, you create a new temp C file which effectively loses memory of any previous read/eval.
- You do not flush after writing the temp C file before compiling it which could cause missing code.

My advice would be to simplify your code without using the temp files to get a proof of concept and then expand from there.

What I've done is at least taken your code and modified it a bit just to prove your thinking is correct. It will work for the example you provided but fail miserably for most anything else. There are many steps to completing your repl assignment that I stopped short of doing, but I hope this gets you on your way:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  static char line[4096];
  char str[256];
  FILE *fp;
  int cnt = 0;
  int isfunc = 0;
  void *handle;
  int (*func)();

  // create a temp file
  const char *cfile = "/tmp/crepltemp.c";
  fp = fopen(cfile, "w+");
  assert(fp);

  while (1) {
    printf("crepl> ");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (!fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
      break;
    }
    sscanf(line, "%s", str);
    if (!strcmp(str, "int")) {  // function, assume it only has int type
      fprintf(fp, "%s", line);
      isfunc = 1;
    } else {  // expression wrapped by function
      fprintf(fp, "int __expr_wrapper_%d() {\n", cnt++);
      fprintf(fp, "\treturn %s;", line);
      fprintf(fp, "}\n");
      isfunc = 0;
    }
    fflush(fp);
    // compile it into shared object
    sprintf(str, "gcc -Wall -Werror -fPIC -shared -o /tmp/crepllib.so %s", cfile);
    system(str);

    // load .so
    handle = dlopen("/tmp/crepllib.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if (!handle) {
      fprintf(stderr, "dlopen error: %s\n", dlerror());
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // find function and invoke it
    if (!isfunc) {  // expression
      sprintf(str, "__expr_wrapper_%d", cnt - 1);
      func = dlsym(handle, str);
      if (!func) {
        fprintf(stderr, "dlsym error: %s\n", dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      printf("%d\n", func());
    } else {      // function
      printf("ok\n");
      if (handle) {
        dlclose(handle);
        handle = NULL;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
% gcc repl.c -Wall -ldl && ./a.out 
crepl> int f() {return 2;}
ok
crepl> f()
2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have solved this problem.  :）

Comment: @sirchen mind giving me a checkmark? :)

Comment: OK ٩(•̤̀ᵕ•̤́๑)ᵒᵏᵎᵎᵎᵎ